# Newbie Debugging a Python Code

Tags: python, python-2.7, super

I want local variable of a class to be changed by other class. My script is similar to the following :

```
import datetime
b = []


class P:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 1
        self.create()

    def create(self):
        global b
        a = C(self.count)
        for i in range(10):
            a.print_name()
        print b


class C:
    def __init__(self, *data):
        self.test = data[0]

    @staticmethod
    def print_name():
        global b
        b.append(datetime.datetime.now())
o = P()
```

How to avoid use of a global variable . On web i found use of "super " can resolve the issue . Please help in this regard .

Answer (score 0):

Make `C` constructor to accept `P` instance. And call the method of `P` to append item to instance attribute of `P` object.

```
class P:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 1
        self.items = []
        self.create()

    def append(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def create(self):
        a = C(self, self.count)  # <-- Pass P instance (self)
        for i in range(10):
            a.print_name()
        print self.items


class C:
    def __init__(self, p_instance, *data):
        self.p_instance = p_instance  # <-- Save P instance to use later
        self.test = data[0]

    def print_name(self):
        self.p_instance.append(datetime.datetime.now())  # <-- Call p instance method
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a class attribute. If you add `b` as an attribute to the `C` class, it can be accessed as `C.b` and `C().b`, i.e. from a reference to the class or any instance.

```
class C(object):  # classes in py2 should inherit from object!
  b = []  # b inside C definition

  @classmethod
  def print_name(cls):
      cls.b.append(datetime.datetime.now())

class P(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.count = 1
    self.create()

  def create(self):
    a = C(self.count)
    for i in range(10):
        a.print_name()
    print C.b  # or a.b
```

Of course, you can also place `b` on `P`. In this case, do

```
  def print_name():
      P.b.append(datetime.datetime.now())
```